# Drawing a map of a city

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So i was given this question. There are only 6 streets in a city. A tourist tried to walk each street just once but then he realized that to see the whole city he needs to walk each street twice. Please draw a possible map of this city.

The part that confuses me is where he needs to walk each street twice. My thoughts that it would simply be a simple graph that connects all the vertices and it would end up looking like a hexagon where in the inside of the hexagon each corner crosses each other to connect the vertices.

Comment: Hint: consider "dead end"/"cul-de-sac" streets

Comment: @angryavian is there a specific similar example that I could relate this too? I have never seen such a question and it was just given to me

Comment: I mean [star graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)).